# How to create new column containing part of the day as ['morning' , 'afternoon' , 'evening', 'night' ] using time column?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am working on time series data and below is how first two columns look. I would like to create new column containing the part of the day or 4 different dataframes consisting of only morning, afternoon, evening, and night times separately.

```
       date       time  
0   2018-11-26  03:40:46.319000     
1   2018-11-26  03:40:46.319999     
2   2018-11-26  03:40:46.319999     
3   2018-11-26  03:40:46.358000     
4   2018-11-26  03:40:46.358000
```

Comment: what determines morning, local sunrise or a defined time ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the hour with dateutil: https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/ or with straight pandas, as shown below:

````
import dateutil

def get_part_of_day(hour):
    return (
        "morning" if 5 <= hour <= 11
        else
        "afternoon" if 12 <= hour <= 17
        else
        "evening" if 18 <= hour <= 22
        else
        "night"
    )

df['part_of_day'] = df.time.apply(lambda x: get_part_of_day(dateutil.parser.parse(x).hour)) 

or without the import dateutil

df['part_of_day'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_part_of_day(pd.to_datetime(x.date + ' ' + x.time).hour), axis=1) 

```
output
```
         date             time part_of_day
0  2018-11-26  03:40:46.319000       night
1  2018-11-26  03:40:46.319999       night
2  2018-11-26  03:40:46.319999       night
3  2018-11-26  03:40:46.358000       night
4  2018-11-26  03:40:46.358000       night
```
````

Answer (score 1):

It is correct to say that your time column is represented as a datetime.time format (e.g. `your_df['time'][0] = datetime.time(3, 40, 46, 319000)`)?
In that case, all you really need to do is to apply take `.hour` attribute of the values in the column to create a new one (and apply some if-statements to determine which hours correspond to morning, afternoon etc.)
Like this:

```
time_col_index = 1
your_df['part of the day'] = df.apply(lambda row: determine_time(row[time_col_index]), axis=1)
```

Where your `determine_time` function could look smth like:

```
def determine_time(time):
    hr = time.hour
    if hr <= 5:
        return night
    elif ...
```